# Why Android Volley Response String is so short

Tags: java, android, android-volley

When I use Android Volley to pull Web HTML Info from web,I found the Response String is so short,that I Can't obtain the useful info.Code below:

```
private static void requestTest(RequestQueue mQueue) {
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest("http://www.baidu.com/",new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String s) {
            Log.v(TAG,"s length="+s.length());   **//Here i Found the length is 7619,it's too short**
            Log.v(TAG,"s="+s.toString());  /**/To Display s on the Console I found the s did not contain the all Info of the web.**
        }
    },new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {

        }
    });
    mQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

Anyone,who knows this question,please tell me!Thanks very!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only log ~4k characters in a single log message. The length you are trying to log is 7k, so it gets trucated. The easiest/quickest workaround is just to split the message into multiple logcat entries, something like:

```
for( String line : s.split("\n") ) {
    Log.d( TAG, line );
}
```

Comment: Thanks Very Much!I found this bug this Morning,and resolved it!Thank you all the same!